# Bibliography display by type?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

this is my first time with LaTeX and i'm a little bit in trouble with bibliography. Is it possible with my set up to cite and make a bibliography as follows:

...Some text (author's lastname and year, p. XX) with books and for online resources this one(title and year).

**Bibliography**

**Books**

author (year). title publisher adress ISBN

**Links**

title (year). author URL

i want to cite like in my example and my bibliography should sort links and books with it's own headlines. Here is my setup :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\onehalfspacing
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\bfseries}

\setcitestyle{aysep={}}

\begin{document}

%===================== Inhaltsverzeichnis ===================%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%======================== Inhalt =========================%
\section{Überschrift}
\subsection{Unterüberschrift}

\cite*[S. 48]{schuermann2015}
\cite*[S. 48]{hetzel2016}
\cite*[S. 48]{wolf2015}
\cite*[S. 48]{cremer2015}
\citep{Tho98w}

%===================Literaturverzeichnis =========================%
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bibliothek}

\end{document}
```

and my .bib file

```
@BOOK{schuermann2015,
    AUTHOR="Tim Schürmann",
    YEAR=2015,
    TITLE="WordPress 4 komplett: Das Kompendium für Websites \& Blogs",
    PUBLISHER="O'Reilly Verlag",
    ADDRESS="Köln",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-95561-854-4"
}

@BOOK{hetzel2016,
    AUTHOR="Alexander Hetzel",
    YEAR=2016,
    TITLE="WordPress 4: Das umfassende Handbuch",
    PUBLISHER="Rheinwerk Verlag",
    ADDRESS="Bonn",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-8362-3943-1"
}

@BOOK{wolf2015,
    AUTHOR="Jürgen Wolf",
    YEAR=2015,
    TITLE="HTML5 und CSS3: Das umfassende Handbuch",
    PUBLISHER="Rheinwerk Verlag",
    ADDRESS="Bonn",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-8362-2885-5"
}

@BOOK{cremer2015,
    AUTHOR="Gino Cremer",
    YEAR=2015,
    TITLE="Das WordPress Praxishandbuch",
    PUBLISHER="Franzis Verlag",
    ADDRESS="München",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-645-60379-9"
}

@MISC{Tho98w,
    Title = "Author",
    Author = "Statistical power analysis software",
    HOWPUBLISHED = "URL: \url{ http://www.forestry.ubc.ca/conservation/power/}",
    YEARr = 1998,
    NOTE ="(besucht am 19.05.2016)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As i said it's my first time using LaTeX and i don't know whats required. I've made a quick search and i think i have to download the biblatex package and install it. But i don't have a clue how to set it up. I'm using Texmaker 4.5

Comment: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7532/wie-unterteile-ich-meine-biblatex-bibliografie and http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have several problems, some related to KOMA-Script (class `scrartcl`), some with your bibliography.

Let's start with KOMA-Script:

- Your line `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}` can you delete, use better the KOMA-Script class option `bibliography=totoc,` instead.
- Change the class options to the way they are used in KOMA-Script. See the changes I did in the following MWE.
- Use better `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`.
- I deleted all packages you loaded in your code which are not neccessary for this problem.

Changings for the bibliography:

- I added `biblatex` (and `csquotes` to avoid a warning)
- I deleted package `natbib`, but added a commented option for `biblatex` for natbib
- I used package `filecontents` to have bib file and TeX file in one compilable code (If you use `MWE.tex` as file name, the `\jobname` changes to `MWE`).
- With `\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}` I changed **only** the `\cite` command to use `()` as you want (`\mkbibparens` does this)
- With `\printbibheading%[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]` the main title for the bibliography is printed. If you want to change it, delete the `%` and change `Literaturverzeichnis` to what you need.
- With `\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Bücher}]` the part of bibliography containing only the cited books.

The changed MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{schuermann2015,
    AUTHOR="Tim Schürmann",
    YEAR=2015,
    TITLE="WordPress 4 komplett: Das Kompendium für Websites \& Blogs",
    PUBLISHER="O'Reilly Verlag",
    ADDRESS="Köln",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-95561-854-4",
}
@BOOK{hetzel2016,
    AUTHOR="Alexander Hetzel",
    YEAR=2016,
    TITLE="WordPress 4: Das umfassende Handbuch",
    PUBLISHER="Rheinwerk Verlag",
    ADDRESS="Bonn",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-8362-3943-1",
}
@BOOK{wolf2015,
    AUTHOR="Jürgen Wolf",
    YEAR=2015,
    TITLE="HTML5 und CSS3: Das umfassende Handbuch",
    PUBLISHER="Rheinwerk Verlag",
    ADDRESS="Bonn",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-8362-2885-5",
}
@BOOK{cremer2015,
    AUTHOR="Gino Cremer",
    YEAR=2015,
    TITLE="Das WordPress Praxishandbuch",
    PUBLISHER="Franzis Verlag",
    ADDRESS="München",
    NOTE="ISBN: 978-3-645-60379-9",
}
@MISC{Tho98w,
    Title = "Author",
    Author = "Statistical power analysis software",
    HOWPUBLISHED = "URL: \url{ http://www.forestry.ubc.ca/conservation/power/}",
    YEAR = 1998,
    NOTE ="(besucht am 19.05.2016)",
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt,
  paper=a4,
  bibliography=totoc, % Bibliography in TOC, numbered with =totocnumbered
  ngerman
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, % bibtex biber
  defernumbers=true,
% natbib=true,
  style=authoryear, % authoryear-comp, authoryear-icomp,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}                  % no punct after entry

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\onehalfspacing


\begin{document}

%===================== Inhaltsverzeichnis ===================%
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

%======================== Inhalt =========================%
\section{Überschrift}
\subsection{Unterüberschrift}

Text~\cite[S.~48]{schuermann2015} Text 
\cite[S.~48]{hetzel2016}
\cite[S.~48]{wolf2015}
\cite[S.~48]{cremer2015}
\cite{Tho98w}

%===================Literaturverzeichnis =========================%
%\clearpage
\printbibheading%[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Bücher}]
\printbibliography[type=misc,heading=subbibliography,title={Online}]

\end{document}
```

results in this pdf:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot and your code looks pretty good. it should be working in my opinion but when executing biber i get the Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.1, expected version 2.9 ... Do i have to downgrade biblatex ? because wheater bibers process is exited normaly the PDFLaTeX causes a lot of errors and warnings which i believe have the same problem